# Multiple buttons to stay focused HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get multiple buttons to stay focused, but haven't had much success.

I have been searching the internet for ages but haven't found an answer that solves my problem.

I want multiple buttons to stay focused. When another button is clicked, the other button keeps it's focus, unless pressed again to lose focus.

```js
function arrangeFocus(){}
```

```css
.button {
width: 70px;
height: 40px;
margin-left: 8px;
background:#63e2c6;
color:#919294;
border:none;
}

.button:active {
background: green;
}
.button:focus {
background: salmon;
}
.button-2 {
width: 70px;
height: 40px;
margin-left: 8px;
background:#63e2c6;
color:#919294;
border:none;
}
.button-3 {
width: 70px;
height: 40px;
margin-left: 8px;
background:#63e2c6;
color:#919294;
border:none;
}

.button-2:active {
background: green;
}
.button-2:focus {
background: salmon;
}

.button-3:active {
background: green;
}
.button-3:focus {
background: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="selected">
        <img src="C:\Users\32635\Documents\aeistore\iph-12.png">
        <h1> Iphone 12 Pro Max/Mini</h1>
        <h3> Selected preset: Iphone 12 6.1 inch display, White, 256GB & No apple care</h3>
        <h3> Package preset price: $1,700 AUD </h3>
        <h3> Free shipping - May vary</h3>
        <h3> Or customize it to your likings:</h3>
        <h3>Colors: <button class="button" id="b1-1">White</button><button class="button" id="b1-2"> black </button><button class="button" id="b1-3">green</button><button class="button" id="b1-4">blue</button><button class="button" id="b1-5">purple</button> red unavailable</h3>
        <h3> Storage: <button class="button-2" id="b2-1">64GB</button><button class="button-2" id="b2-2">128GB</button><button class="button-2" id="b2-3">256GB</button></h3>
        <h3> Type: <button class="button-3" id="b3-1"> iPhone 12 Mini (5.4 Inch display)</button><button class="button-3" id="b3-2">iPhone 12 (6.1 inch display)</button></h3>
    </div>
```

My javascript is just empty.

So how can I do this?

Comment: you can "fake" the behave of focus by adding class to button and style the class as focus would do

Answer (score 0):

The item with the focus is the item that the user is *currently interacting with*. It's the keyboard navigation equivalent to pointing at something with the mouse. They can only interact with one thing at a time.

If you want something to represent a toggle state, use a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Focus can't work this way as the whole point of it is that is represents the place the user is currently interacting - and that can't be two places at once.

What your use case seems to need is grouped radio buttons. Each of the categories could have a set of radio inputs with the user selecting just one of each.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Convert each of your `button` elements to `input` elements with `type=radio` and style them (with label elements too) and group them using `name`. That way each of the 3 lists can only have one thing selected, which is what you want, but you can have one selected from each list all at the same time.